# Removing zero dot after solving

Tags: numerics, output-formatting, output

I've a question regarding "zero dots". Im using a lot of calculation in an application which i am building within mathematica. However when i use the output of solve for instant i will not have the dot after a numerical solution (see picture below for example (after "25"). Is there some way i can remove the dot after a soultion. The best would be if i could do it to the whole notebook at once bcs there are a lot of calculations.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Round` or `Rationalize`?

Comment: If you use integers or rational numbers Solve will return numbers without a dot

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Note that `25` and `25.` are different object, the first an `Integer` and the second a `Real`.  Of course they are denoted in different ways.

Comment: Maybe `expr /. x_Real /; x == Round[x] :> NumberForm[x, NumberPoint -> ""]` or  `expr /. x_Real /; x == Round[x] :> Round[x]`

Comment: Please do not post separate question if you want to make an edit to the original one. There is 'edit' link below the question body.

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* supports two arithmetic systems, exact arithmetic and inexact arithmetic. Inexact arithmetic subdivides into machine arithmetic and arbitrary precision arithmetic. Machine arithmetic is the default, which is what you are seeing.

Inexact arithmetic will always display with decimal markers. You can convert inexact arithmetic values to exact values with functions such as [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and [`Round`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html).